# Insert into mysql database using case statement

Tags: php, mysql

This is my first question in this site and i hope you can help me
I have registration page and one of the fields is a drop down list that contains three values: 1st try, 2nd try, 3rd try.

I need to make a query to insert these values to my database. If i select 1st try, the value "you can pass next exam" must entered to database; when i choose 2nd try from drop down list, the value "you cant pass exam" must be entered to database...

in other words, how can I select a value in my form and insert a different value into the database?

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$c=$_POST['c'];


$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(name, password, rate)VALUES('$name','$password', '$c')";
```

value of c = 1st try then "you can pass next exam" must be entered
when value of c= 2nd then "you can not pass next exam" must be entered

Comment: dear post your code. Thanks

Comment: please post a sample code. Then we will happily help you.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its Pretty simple

You can just go Like this

```
<select>
<option value="you can pass next exam">1st try</option>
<option value="you cant pass next exam">2st try</option>
</select>
```

This will post the value in the option so its easy to save the same what you get, you dont need to case with the option you receive